# active record contains query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

how can I implement "contains function" in active records? 
I am trying to query my database which contains the following data as an example

brand: ipad
model : ipad 3gen
specs : wifi+3g 32 GB black

when the user searched for "ipad black 3gen" he should get the above record.

this is my trail which didnt work

```
    @products = Product.where("brand like ? OR generation like ? OR spec_overview like ? ", "%"+params[:query].capitalize+"%", "%"+params[:query].capitalize+"%", "%"+params[:query].capitalize+"%")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql is not a great fit for this type of query. You can do it with a fulltext index probably, but using something like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) would be much less painful, and more accurate. You can integrate Solr into a Rails app with [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/) if you decide to go that direction.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure there is sql solution to this since it is a common design pattern.